# Blazor WASM, Logging Async Method Exceptions. blazor-error-ui

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

How does aspnetcore framework set this div to display block in a Blazor WASM app?

```
<div id="blazor-error-ui" style="display: none;">
```

I've searched the code in https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore, but doesn't seem to be anywhere in that source.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

I created a custom logger following this MS doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/logging?view=aspnetcore-6.0 to attempt to log all exceptions.  This seemed to work, however it does not capture exceptions thrown by async methods.  I tried using ErrorBoundary components as well, but those also fail to catch exeptions thrown by async methods.

Curiously, when an exception is thrown from an async method, the exception is logged to the console, does not get passed to the custom logger, and the blazor-error_ui div is still toggled to.

```
<div id="blazor-error-ui" style="display: block;">
```

So the framework must be aware of this exception...shouldn't it be able to be captured/logged?

Comment: Are you so kind to create a Minimal Reproducible Example? Thanks [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Btw, https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web.JS/src/BootErrors.ts

Comment: Error boundaries does capture Async methods are you waiting them?

Answer (score 1):

Though I can't know for sure without seeing your code, I suspect these async methods that are throwing an exception need to be awaited where they are called.  If a task from an async call is never awaited, the calling context could very well complete successfully before the async call is done, and thus there is nothing in your code that could catch an exception out of the "orphaned" async task.

If this doesn't seem right, please show us the code of how you call one of these async methods that throws this uncaught exception, as well as the code of your custom logger.